systemd not finding executable
Using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, I have this unit file:
#Installed in the global system
#
# /lib/systemd/system/flm.service
# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl stop flm.service
# systemctl start flm.service
# systemctl status flm.service
#
# Installed in user space
#
# ~/.config/systemd/user/flm.service
#
# systemctl --user daemon-reload
# systemctl --user stop flm.service
# systemctl --user start flm.service
# systemctl --user status flm.service

[Unit]
Description=FourJs License Manager 6.00.13-202303241116
After=network.target nss-lookup.target
Documentation=https://4js.com/online_documentation/fjs-flm-manual-html

[Service]
Type=exec
Environment="FLMDIR=/tmp/flm"
ExecStartPre=/tmp/flm/bin/flmprg -a env
ExecStart=/tmp/flm/bin/flmprg -D
ExecReload=/tmp/flm/bin/flmprg --service-restart
ExecStop=/tmp/flm/bin/flmprg --service-stop
KillMode=mixed
Restart=on-abort
SuccessExitStatus=SIGTERM 0
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


When I try to start the service, I get:
ubuntu@ip-172-30-2-235:/tmp/flm/bin$ systemctl status flm.service
× flm.service - FourJs License Manager 6.00.13-202303241116
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/flm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2024-08-07 01:35:16 UTC; 6s ago
       Docs: https://4js.com/online_documentation/fjs-flm-manual-html
    Process: 15296 ExecStartPre=/tmp/flm/bin/flmprg -a env (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
        CPU: 3ms

Aug 07 01:35:16 ip-172-30-2-235 systemd[1]: Starting FourJs License Manager 6.00.13-202303241116...
Aug 07 01:35:16 ip-172-30-2-235 systemd[15296]: flm.service: Failed to locate executable /tmp/flm/bin/flmprg: No such file or directory
Aug 07 01:35:16 ip-172-30-2-235 systemd[15296]: flm.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /tmp/flm/bin/flmprg: No such file or directory
Aug 07 01:35:16 ip-172-30-2-235 systemd[1]: flm.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Aug 07 01:35:16 ip-172-30-2-235 systemd[1]: flm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 07 01:35:16 ip-172-30-2-235 systemd[1]: Failed to start FourJs License Manager 6.00.13-202303241116.

However, the file is definitely there and executable, as if I cut and past the path from the error message and take on the switches from the unit file, I can run it as user ubuntu from the command line:
ubuntu@ip-172-30-2-235:/tmp/flm/bin$  /tmp/flm/bin/flmprg -a env
Hostname: ip-172-30-2-235
FLM server: localhost
FLM service: 6811
FLM pidfile: /tmp/flm/pidfile
Log directory: /tmp/flm
Log categories: error,warning,info
Log enabled: false
Log max files: 0
Client ping interval: 30

Permissions of the directories involved:
drwxrwxrwt 12 root root     4096   Aug  7 02:04 tmp
drwxrwxrwx 10 ubuntu ubuntu 4096   Aug  7 01:54 flm
drwxrwxrwx  2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096   May 17 17:08 bin
-rwxrwxrwx  1 ubuntu ubuntu 472848 May 17 17:08 flmprg

If anyone has any ideas where I'm going wrong with this, it would be much appreciated.

Does /tmp/flm/bin/flmprg exist? Is it executable? /tmp/ is a poor choice for software installation, sometimes it gets blown away and recreated empty. Read man hier, and use the /usr/local/... tree.

It does exist and is executable; the directories and file I listed above show the permissions at the various levels.
The path works fine outside of the unit file.
And yes, I don't love where it was installed, but I don't think that should be impacting systemd being able to find and execute /tmp/flm/bin/flmprg.

If you set PrivateTmp=true, who is going to put those files in the private /tmp of this service?

I commented out PrivateTmp=true and it doesn't seem to change anything:
ubuntu@ip-172-30-2-235:/lib/systemd/system$ grep PrivateTmp flm.service
#PrivateTmp=true

Output with #PrivateTMP:
Aug 07 03:17:01 ip-172-30-2-235 bash[916]: bash: /tmp/flm/bin/flmprg: No such file or directory

Did you reload after that?

I think you've misunderstood the installation instructions. It says there you should use a dedicated installation directory such as one under /opt, and that it needs a dedicated temporary directory in /tmp

The first thing I would try is to change the installation location and use the systemd https://4js.com/online_documentation/fjs-flm-manual-html/#genero-install-topics/r_flm_systemd_template.html as is. This could be a problem related to the AppArmor security module.
